# How can I enable Android GUI to unlock SIM PIN after booting?

Tags: java, c++, android, c

I'm a android RIL driver developer. I had implement "Change SIM PIN" function (RIL write AT command to modem). But when SIM card status is "SIM_PIN" (require PIN code to unlock SIM card), the "Change SIM PIN" function would be failed. How can I enable Android GUI to unlock SIM PIN after booting?

Comment: I've a problem where a call using in car bluetooth results in the phone application crashing after I hang up.  I then need to put the PIN in (defeating the purpose of "hands free").  The answer to this might allow me to detect the crash and in that case automatically add the PIN.

Comment: Maybe it is better to identify the Application causing the crash and to use a replacement than to work around this?

Comment: @Richard: If you want to automatically unlock after a crash you can simple disable the sim pin at all.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the thoughts.  Re the app, it's actually com.android.phone that crashes - do you know of a replacement (I've not rooted the phone).  I would prefer not to disable the pin on the sim.

Comment: you can also apply PIN by Android app as I describe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323484/access-to-standard-android-settings-pin-code-of-the-sim-card/16795637#16795637

Answer (score 0):

If you've been able to implement a change sim pin function (AT+CLCK I believe), then I assume you're in a position to implement an 'Enter PIN' function (AT+CPIN="pin_no") .

Just call this function before your change sim pin function.