# Access to standard android settings: PIN code of the SIM card

Tags: android, android-widget

This is my first question!
I'd like to know how to access to standard settings in android, in particular SIM features.
On boot, my Samsung i-9000 shows the window for insert the PIN code only for a few seconds, then disappears, so I'd like to develop by myself a widget for the homescreen that launch the standard window to insert the PIN code, but I don't know how can I do it!

Or someway to change the screen timeout of that window...

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

By using the TelephonyManager in Android.
You do not instantiate this class directly; instead, you retrieve a reference to an instance through Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
int state = manager.getSimState();
if(state == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED || state == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED)
{
         //PIN/PUK is required
}
```

May this will help you ...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but the issue is another one.
I saw your solution in another question, but this solution tells me only if PIN is required, but not how to set it! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to apply PIN in Android above 2.3 version, you have to install your app as a system app, in both cases you should use this code:

```java
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
    Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
    m.setAccessible(true);
    ITelephony telephonyService;
    telephonyService = (ITelephony)m.invoke(tm);

    // Supply  SIM PIN
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(OrangeSignalMeterLoop.class.getCanonicalName()+"x", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(prefs.getBoolean(context.getString(R.string.whetherAutoCompletePIN), false)) {
        String sim_pin = prefs.getString(context.getString(R.string.pinCode), "1111");  
        telephonyService.supplyPin(sim_pin);
    }
```

You probably will not be able use Internal class, the best tutorial how to use it you'll find here: https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/